# Change the font size of a ggplot chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

In a ggplot chart I have a title for chart and values for x and y axis. When I save the chart as an image the labels are tiny.

I tried to change the font size using:

```
size = 21
```

But it didn't work. Is there any easy way to chage the font size for the whole chart?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Size of texts are changed using function `theme()` and then choosing element you need to modify. To set font size for all texts in plots attribute `text` should be changed.

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(cyl,mpg))+geom_point()+theme(text=element_text(size=21))
```

Comment: I don't think this is exactly what this command is doing. What this does is it scales up and down the default font sizes already in place.  However, it does not standardize all fonts to a single size.  I would love to know how to do that if you know.

Answer (score 16):

There are two ways to set the global font size in a ggplot object
`p = ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y))`. As Didzis pointed out one can specify:

```r
global_size = 10
p + theme(text = element_text(size=global_size))
```

Alternatively, if you are using one of the ggplot themes, pass `base_size` argument:

```r
p +  theme_classic(base_size = global_size)
```

This is subjective, but I would advise against using font size 21. It is better to use "standard" font sizes (9-12 pt) and adjust the `height` and `width` when saving the ggplot object to match your final printed output.

Just measure the width / height in inches (or cm) of the figure in your presentation, report, etc and save the plot `p` with exactly those dimensions

```r
ggsave(p, filename=filename,
 width=width_measured, height=height_measured, units='cm')
```

Comment: Posters may require larger fonts